Netsuite: Getting price interval for specific date with SuiteScript 1.0
In the Netsuite REST API, it is possible to query the priceintervals for a specific subscription through this endpoint:
/record/v1/subscription/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/priceInterval
This will return a list of priceintervals for each subscription line. For example, the following is the excerpt of the response that concerns subscription line number 16:
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://XXXXXXXXX.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/subscription/123456/priceInterval/subscriptionPlanLineNumber=16,startDate=2024-06-05"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://XXXXXXXXX.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/subscription/123456/priceInterval/subscriptionPlanLineNumber=16,startDate=2024-08-01"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "https://XXXXXXXXX.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/subscription/123456/priceInterval/subscriptionPlanLineNumber=16,startDate=2024-08-11"
            }
        ]
    },

Then, by visiting the relevant URL, I can get details about the state of the subscription line at that point in time (e.g. quantity, amount, status, etc).
In SuiteScript 1.0, something similar can be done by first loading the subscription:
let subscriptionId = 123456;
let subscription = nlapiLoadRecord('subscription', subscriptionId, {
    "recordmode": "dynamic"
});

and then querying the line, for example:
let lineNumber = 16;
let quantity = subscription.getLineItemValue('subscriptionline', 'quantity', lineNumber);

However - and this is my question - this seems to always return the quantity for the very first priceinterval of the subscription (the one with startDate=2024-06-05). How do I use SuiteScript 1.0 to query for the quantity at a specific time interval of the subscription, i.e. the last one with startDate=2024-08-11?
Any help or ideas greatly appreciated.
